# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null even though database object is initialised

Tags: php

I get an error saying that the prepare function is on null, I've had this before and could fix it no problem but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong right now. The fatal error is showing:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on
>   null in C:\xampp\htdocs\OOP\Artist-System\classes\Db.php:43 Stack
>   trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\OOP\Artist-System\classes\Artist.php(94):
>   Db->query('SELECT name, pl...', Array) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\OOP\Artist-System\index.php(11): Artist->select() #2
>   {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\OOP\Artist-System\classes\Db.php on
>   line 43

Db class:

```
class Db
{
    private $servername;
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $dbname;
    private $charset;

public function __construct($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, $charset)
{
    $this->servername = $servername;
    $this->username = $username;
    $this->password = $password;
    $this->dbname = $dbname;
    $this->charset = $charset;
}

private function connect()
{
    try {
        $dsn = "mysql:host=".$this->servername.";dbname=".$this->dbname.";charset=".$this->charset;
        $options = [
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
        ];
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->username, $this->password, $options);
        return $pdo;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function query($query, $data)
{
    $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($data);
    $queryWords = explode(' ', trim($query));
    if ($queryWords[0] == "SELECT") {
        return $stmt->fetchAll();
    }
}
```

Artist class where the error is located at line 93-94:

```
public function select()
{
    $select = "SELECT name, playcount, listeners, image FROM artist";
    return $this->db->query($select, array());
}
```

Comment: Check database is connected or not

Comment: try to echo the message `echo $e->getMessage();`

Comment: Saw the fix while looking at the post, thanks anyways.